# Invalid Project Binding when Adding New Project

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I always get an invalid binding when adding a new c# project to my solution which is resulting in the files not being added to TFS. The only solution at this moment is to remove the binding and add the project to source control again.

Just a few details,

- The project is generated from a project that was created by exporting one of our other projects to the templates folder
- Using VS 2015
- Using TFS 2015

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue always happens when you copy one source controlled solution to another source control solution. After unbinding the invalid project, unload the project and reload it should solve this issue.

Check blog: http://samirvaidya.blogspot.com/2015/02/fixing-invalid-tfs-source-control.html

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on the answer given by @Cece, I deleted the

```
<SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
```

entries from my .proj file in my template folder and everythin worked from there